# How to add multiple ac dimmer to a single arduino?

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

Busy programmers,

Novice here, I wrote a code for multiple ac dimmers that are controlled by a single Arduino Uno, yup consider they are quite high it would mean I cannot use uno and will have to move to due. I just want to know, is my code executable. How do I change it for two ac dimmers. do I use another output pin for the same program. I have difficulty executing multiple ac dimmers, never worked with them, need help, fellow overlords. the toggling is a loop function.

```
   
#include <RBDdimmer.h>//

//#define USE_SERIAL  SerialUSB //Serial for boards whith USB serial port
#define USE_SERIAL  Serial
#define outputPin  12 
#define zerocross  5 // for boards with CHANGEBLE input pins

//dimmerLamp dimmer(outputPin, zerocross); //initialase port for dimmer for ESP8266, ESP32, Arduino due boards
dimmerLamp dimmer(outputPin); //initialase port for dimmer for MEGA, Leonardo, UNO, Arduino M0, Arduino Zero

int outVal = 0;

void setup() {
 USE_SERIAL.begin(9600); 
 dimmer.begin(NORMAL_MODE, ON); //dimmer initialisation: name.begin(MODE, STATE) 
 USE_SERIAL.println("Dimmer Program is starting...");
 USE_SERIAL.println("Set value");
}

void printSpace(int val)
{
 if ((val / 100) == 0) USE_SERIAL.print(" ");
 if ((val / 10) == 0) USE_SERIAL.print(" ");
}

void loop() {
 int preVal = outVal;

 if (USE_SERIAL.available())
 {
   int buf = USE_SERIAL.parseInt();
   if (buf != 0) outVal = buf;
   delay(200);
 }
 dimmer.setPower(outVal); // setPower(0-100%);

 if (preVal != outVal)
 {
   USE_SERIAL.print("lampValue -> ");
   printSpace(dimmer.getPower());
   USE_SERIAL.print(dimmer.getPower());
   USE_SERIAL.println("%");

 }
 delay(50);


void loop() {
USE_SERIAL.begin(9600);
 dimmer.begin(TOGGLE_MODE, OFF); //dimmer initialisation: name.begin(MODE, STATE) 
 USE_SERIAL.println("--- Toggle dimmer example ---");
 dimmer.toggleSettings(0, 100); //Name.toggleSettings(MIN, MAX);
 dimmer.setState(ON); // state: dimmer1.setState(ON/OFF);
 pinMode(14, INPUT);
}
```

Comment: `dimmerLamp dimmer2(outputPin2); `

Comment: Is it that simple?

Comment: what's that supposed to mean? "yup consider they are quite high it would mean I cannot use uno and will have to move to due."

Comment: I will be using this code for 45 ac dimmers, so I don't think a single Arduino UNO will work for it, thus,I will have to move to Arduino due for that purpose.

Comment: the library has 30 dimmers max. you have to change the define in library for more dimmers. I think Mega can handle it. there is only one zero crossing detection for all and the triacs are handled in timer interrupt every 12 microseconds

Comment: Okay got that, will try, but after running the code i get error  I ran the code, but now it is saying ' redefinition of the void loop"  I know I have used multiple loops so how to get around it.

Comment: no I got that, I was using the loop function multiple times. Thank you for your suggestion.